# Add alt text to image in cute slider wordpress plugin

Tags: php, wordpress, function, alt

Below is the PHP code for the images section in my website using the Cute slider plugin. I am trying to add `alt` text by adding text to the line `$data .= '<img '.$src.''.$datasrc.''.$thumb.'>';` but the `alt` text ends up duplicated. Where should I add the `alt` text?

```
if($layerkey == 0) {
    $src = ' src="'.$layer['properties']['image'].'"';
    $datasrc = '';
}
else {
    $src = ' src="'.$GLOBALS['csPluginPath'].'/img/blank.png" width="1" height="1" alt="Blank"';
    $datasrc = ' data-src="'.$layer['properties']['image'].'"';
}

$data .= '<li data-delay="'.$layer['properties']['slidedelay'].'" data-src="'.$layer['properties']['slidedelay'].'" data-trans3d="'.$layer['properties']['3d_transitions'].'" data-trans2d="'.$layer['properties']['2d_transitions'].'">';

$data .= '<img '.$src.''.$datasrc.''.$thumb.'>';
```

The full php file is here : http://pastie.org/9167151

Comment: I tried to add alt" " at this code `$data .= '<img '.$src.''.$datasrc.''.$thumb.'>'` at line 170 but it gives me duplicated alt. and isn't working is the alt attribute in slider images, always show missing alt.

Comment: Can you please post the relevant code to this website? It is very difficult to work with that external site. You can format the code by clicking the curly braces button `{}` in the editor, indenting it by 4 spaces, or pressing CTRL-K

Comment: Thank you for interesting, i have added the code to the question.

Comment: On this line :`$src = ' src="'.$GLOBALS['csPluginPath'].'/img/blank.png" width="1" height="1" alt="Blank"';` `alt` is already defined, that is why you get two definitions. You should change the definition on that line.

Comment: @darthbith I'll try that and let you know. Thank you.

Comment: @darthbith Thank you very much, finally it worked :) Now, how to choose and vote for your answer?

Comment: I have edited your question to actually ask the question that you had. Please closely review my edit and try to ask questions like this in the future - it will help you get help faster! :-) Anyways, I've added my answer as an answer. If this solves your problem, you can click the green check-mark under the up and down arrows to mark it "accepted".

Answer (score 0):

On this line: `$src = ' src="'.$GLOBALS['csPluginPath'].'/img/blank.png" width="1" height="1" alt="Blank"';` `alt` is already defined, that is why you get two definitions when you try to add it in the second place. You should change the definition on that line instead of on the `$data .= '<img '.$src.''.$datasrc.''.$thumb.'>';` line.